# EOFError in python win32com

Tags: python, win32com, eoferror

I am running Sympathy for Data, a program based on python. It worked well until today. I got error message like this:

```
File "..\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
import gencache
File >"..\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 662, in <module>
_ _init_ _()
File >"..\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 56, in _ _init_ _
_LoadDicts()
File "..\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 109, in _LoadDicts
version = p.load()
EOFError
```

I find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065093/eoferror-randomly-appeared-while-using-pyttsx-and-my-code-now-constantly-throws) which basically had the same issue, but the solution doesn't work for me. All the solutions that I've found online provide the same solution, remove the contents under _gen_py_ folder.

I don't have to run any program with Sympathy for data. I got this error message even if I open the iPython shipped with Sympathy for data.

I am really hopeless in this case, could someone help me how to solve it?

Comment: So you have deleted `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\dicts.dat` and still get the problem?

Comment: @SiHa yes, I did delete the _dicts.dat_ file. Well actually the folder name on my path is `...\win32com\_gen_py_\dicts.dat`, and I try to remove all the contents under that folder, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when I had to reboot the system when it was running a program using win32com. I was using an Py2.7 anaconda environment and couldn't find `dicts.dat` file in my anaconda folder. I later found that is is actually stored in a temporary directory `\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\2.7` I deleted that and it solved the error.

Answer (score -1):

I think uninstalling the package using CMD(Administrator) 
using

> pip uninstall pywin32

and again installing it by collecting new data using no saved cache using

> pip --no-cache install pywin32

will help you a lot